# Loosing header row when filtering a table (java/html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I noticed that when filtering through a custom table I made, I am loosing the first header row that allows users to sort my table. Any one know what is wrong with my code? (the following snippet is the first row)

```
<th onclick="sortTable(0)"style="background-color:DeepSkyBlue;">Name</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(1)"style="background-color:DeepSkyBlue;">Year</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(2)"style="background-color:DeepSkyBlue;">State</th>
```

The above snippet is the top/first row that disappears as soon as text input is put into a search box. (I am leaving out some code because I know the problem is in the script(s) below)

There are two scripts below, the top is the ability to sort all columns, not just the first. And the bottom script is the input text/filtering.

```
<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
      match = false;
      for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this test

```
if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
```

Your headers are expected to have a `class` attribute with the keyword "header"

```
<th class="header"                   <- this is missing?
    onclick="sortTable(0)"
    style="background-color:DeepSkyBlue;">Name</th>
```

You could also use the same trick as in the other loop at start with `i = 1`.

Comment: Solved! Thanks! I was missing the header class and i=1 worked. Thanks